# Minkowski dimension behaviour of sets with positive finite Hausdorff measure.

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory

It is (rather) well known that the set
\begin{equation*}
E=\{k^{-1},k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\}
\end{equation*}
has box-dimension $1/2$ and Hausdorff dimension $0$. However $H^{0}(E)=|E|=+\infty$.

Is it possible to find a set $E$ with Minkowski dimension $s$ for which $0<H^{s'}(E)<+\infty$ for some $s'\neq s$ ? I haven't been able to construct one, neither in $\mathbb{R}$ nor in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. I'm enclined to think that it is possible, since geometric measure theory books (Falconer, Perrti-Mattila) heavily insist on the fact that it is very difficult to get results relating Minkowski and Hausdorff dimensions.

Note that if such a set exists then $s>s'>0$ automatically.

Comment: How about $E\cup C$, where $E$ is your set above and $C$ is a Cantor type set of dimension $s'<1/2$?  Though, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @MarkMcClure I think your comment is the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot I did not think of that ! If you write an answer I'll accept it. Also, I asked this looking for inspiration for another question, if you want to check it out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101940/upper-minkowski-content-and-finite-hausdorff-measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A requested example was given by [Mark McClure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101735/minkowski-dimension-behaviour-of-sets-with-positive-finite-hausdorff-measure#comment2246392_1101735) in a comment:

> How about $E\cup C$, where $E$ is your set above and $C$ is a Cantor type set of dimension $s'<1/2$?

That is, consider the union of a countable set of Minkowski dimension $1/2$ and of a self-similar Cantor set of Hausdorff (and Minkowski) dimension $s'<1/2$.

- The Minkowski dimension of the union is $1/2$.
- The Hausdorff dimension of the union is $s'<1/2$.
- The $s'$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is positive and finite on the union.